# How do I define and call a function using LLVM Module-Level Inline Assembly?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

LLVM has a feature that lets us drop native assembly instructions directly into an `.ll` file.

```
 module asm "inline asm code goes here"
```

https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#module-level-inline-assembly

And indeed, the `.s` output file contains these instructions.

But how can I write a complete function that way and call into it from LLVM-code in the same file?

Can someone provide a simple example `.ll` where the `@main()` written in LLVM-code calls into a function defined in an inline `module asm` (ideally passing a parameter or two) and exits with the return value of that?

I am asking because I want to port [this code](https://gist.github.com/FiloSottile/7125822) from NASM to LLIR. It outputs Hello World directly using system calls, without linking against a standard library (so if there is a way to do system calls without needing to drop into native assembly, I'd like to hear about that as well).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if llvm module level inline assembly works with nasm flavour.
hope below listed example will give some insight. basically we want to declare the function in llvm ir which will be resolved at link time.

```
; source_filename = file.ll

module asm ".format:"
module asm "    .string \22%d, hello world %s\n\22"
module asm "    .text"
module asm "    .globl print"
module asm "    .type print @function"
module asm "print:"
module asm "        pushq   %rbp"
module asm "        movq    %rsp, %rbp"
module asm "        subq    $16, %rsp"
module asm "        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)"
module asm "        movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)"
module asm "        movq    -16(%rbp), %rdx"
module asm "        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax"
module asm "        movl    %eax, %esi"
module asm "        leaq    .format(%rip), %rdi"
module asm "        movl    $0, %eax"
module asm "        call    printf@PLT"
module asm "        movq    %rbp, %rsp"
module asm "        popq    %rbp"
module asm "        ret"

@.str = global [16 x i8] c", how are you?\0A\00"

declare void @print(i64, i8*)

define i32 @main() {
start:
  %cast210 = getelementptr [16 x i8], [16 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0
  call void @print(i64 10, i8* %cast210)
  ret i32 0
}
```

to compile and run

```
llc file.ll -filetype=obj -o file.o
ld -o test ./file.o -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o -lc -melf_x86_64
./test
```

Comment: Thanks, will try later. It does not have to be NASM syntax. Why call `gcc` at the end? Doesn't llvm include a tool to do that?

Comment: yes, gcc is not needed here any sane linker(llvm have lld, you can use lld, ld or gold-ld) would do the job, as assembly subroutine was using "printf" std lib linking was needed and frankly i got lazy resolving external c-runtime dependencies.